# Count the number of spaces in a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am working on data validation and I am trying to count the number of spaces in a string. My problem is that when I count the spaces, any sting with more than one space between texts or any string with trailing space(s) are not counted
I have tried the following codes without luck. each codes gives different result but not the desired output

```
DECLARE @MyTbl TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @MyTBL VALUES
(1, 'Alfreds Futterkiste'), -- 1 space
(2,'Mike James Ray  '),     -- 4 spaces 1 space between each text and 2 spaces after text
(3,'Hanari  Carnes'),       -- 2 spaces between text
(4,'James Michael')

-- 1
SELECT ID,
LEN(Name)-LEN(REPLACE(Name, ' ', '')) AS Count_Of_Spaces 
FROM  @MyTBL
-- 2
SELECT ID,
LEN(Name + ';')-LEN(REPLACE(Name,' ','')) AS Count_Of_Spaces2 
FROM  @MyTBL
-- 3
SELECT ID,
LEN(Name)-LEN(REPLACE(Name,' ', '')) AS Count_Of_Spaces3  
FROM  @MyTBL
```

Current output based on the first query

```
 ID Count_Of_Spaces
  1    1
  2    2
  3    2
  4    1
```

Desired output

```
 ID Count_Of_Spaces
 1     1
 2     4
 3     2
 4     1
```

Comment: `LEN` never includes trailing spaces because comparisons never respect trailing spaces (this is considered a feature). Use `DATALENGTH` instead, but mind that for `NVARCHAR` strings the results of that need to be divided by 2. (Although your second query/trick is already almost correct; just subtract 1 more from the result.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could use [`DATALENGTH`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datalength-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

```
SELECT ID,
DATALENGTH(Name)-LEN(REPLACE(Name,' ', '')) AS Count_Of_Spaces
FROM  @MyTBL;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=607e17cd2c900ab293ed8a06ac9b2ca3)**

[`LEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/len-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) does not count trailing spaces.

---

If `NVARCHAR` then you need to divide by 2.

```
DECLARE @MyTbl TABLE (ID INT, Name NVARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @MyTBL VALUES
(1, 'Alfreds Futterkiste'), -- 1 space
(2,'Mike James Ray  '),     -- 4 spaces 1 space between 
                            -- each text and 2 spaces after text
(3,'Hanari  Carnes'),       -- 2 spaces between text
(4,'James Michael');

SELECT ID,
DATALENGTH(Name)/2-LEN(REPLACE(Name,' ', '')) AS Count_Of_Spaces
FROM  @MyTBL;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=663b136d47580230566ab0235c7a8349)**

Answer (score 1):

You had the answer in your attempt #2.  Probably just didn't realize to do the appending in the second part(`REPLACE`) of your query

```
DECLARE @MyTbl TABLE (ID INT, Name VARCHAR(300))
INSERT INTO @MyTBL VALUES
(1, 'Alfreds Futterkiste'), -- 1 space
(2,'Mike James Ray  '),     -- 4 spaces 1 space between each text and 2 spaces after text
(3,'Hanari  Carnes'),       -- 2 spaces between text
(4,'James Michael')


-- 2
SELECT ID,
LEN(';' + Name + ';')-LEN(REPLACE(';' + Name + ';',' ','')) AS Count_Of_Spaces2 
FROM  @MyTBL
```

Answer (score 0):

When I need the length of a field passed into a function or stored procedure and the field could have trailing spaces that are meant to be there, I use the following statement:-

```
@Len = LEN(@Parm + '.') - 1
```